# Contour integrals, residues, and changes of variables

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Maybe this is a little contrived; I'm trying to understand how a change of variables will change how to compute a residue or contour integral. Anyway, suppose we have complex contour integral

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{1}{1-ez}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $\epsilon > 0$ centered around $0$. Now suppose we change variables via $z=e^{-\zeta}$, the above becomes
$$\frac{-1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma'} \frac{1}{1-e^{1-\zeta}}e^{n\zeta}d\zeta.$$

For the first integral it would be sufficient to compute the residue of the integrand. After the change of variables, the integrand now has a pole at $\zeta=1$ but the curve $\gamma'$ isn't closed.

**Question:** *Can we evaluate the first integral by first making the change of variables and then considering the residue of the integrand of the second integral at $\zeta=1$*?

Comment: Why does $\gamma'$ go off to infinity? Isn't it just a line segment from $-\log\epsilon$ to $-\log\epsilon+2\pi\mathrm i$ (or some translated version of that)? Also, what do you mean when you say it "contains" $\zeta=1$ (since it's not closed)? I also don't understand the contrast you suggest by "though" and "now". The original integrand has a pole at $z=\mathrm e^{-1}$, and the new integrand has a corresponding pole at $\zeta=1$.

Comment: @joriki Thanks! I think my question is better stated as "can we evaluate the first integral by understanding the residues of the poles of the second integral?"

Comment: Use $\oint$ for contour integrals and $\int$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't think we can, since, as you note, the contour isn't closed in the $\zeta$ plane.

Comment: Why do you think $z=e^{-\zeta}$ is a valid change of variables? What is the inverse?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's easy straight away with the residue theorem.